# How to create a variable that is char *[] so it can be passed to a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to pass an argument to a function that takes a `char *[]` as input:

```
int nArgs = 0;
CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &nArgs);
const int commandLineArgsBufferSize = 500;
char commandLineArgs[commandLineArgsBufferSize];
wcstombs(commandLineArgs, GetCommandLineW(), commandLineArgsBufferSize);
int result = Catch::Session().run(nArgs, &commandLineArgs);
```

Here is the function prototype.

```
int Session::run( int argc, char* argv[] );
```

I am getting a compiler error:

> C2664 'int Catch::Session::run(void)': cannot convert argument 2 from 'char (*)[500]' to 'char *[]'

Comment: You have created a pointer to a char array, you need an array of pointers to chars

Comment: Your function takes an array of `char*`, but you pass a pointer to an array of `char`

Answer (score 0):

The function is presumably intended to take the parameters of main() as arguments. So you want something like:

```
 int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
     int rv = Session::run( argc, argv );
 }
```

If you wanted to construct the arguments yourself, something like:

```
 void f() {
     char * argv[] = {"foo", "bar" };
     int rv =  Session::run( 2, argv );
 }
```

Comment: Would something like this work.  
    const int commandLineArgsBufferSize = 2^10;
     char commandLineArgs[commandLineArgsBufferSize];
     wcstombs(commandLineArgs, GetCommandLineW(), 
         commandLineArgsBufferSize);
     char * commandLineArgsToPass[] = { commandLineArgs };
    int result = Catch::Session().run(nArgs, commandLineArgsToPass);

Comment: @Donald Nope - that makes no  sense. Do you know what the `^` operator does? You seem to be way over-thinking this.